# What is use of performSelector in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector

What is the role of **performSelector**?

Comparing:

```
[self btnClicked];
```

and

```
[self performSelector:@selector(btnClicked)];

-(void)btnClicked
{
    NSLog(@"Method Called");
}
```

both are woking fine for me. What is difference between these two. `[self btnClicked]` and `[self performSelector:@selector(btnClicked)]`;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two are pretty identical when used as you have demonstrated, but the latter has the advantage that you can dynamically determine which selector to call at runtime.

```
SEL selector = [self gimmeASelectorToCall];
[self performSelector: selector];
```

[<sub>[Source]</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1493182/916299)

Answer (score 8):

Apple doc is your friend.

[NSObject Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

It

> Sends a specified message to the receiver and returns the result of
>   the message.

In particular:

> The `performSelector:` method **is equivalent to sending an aSelector
>   message directly to the receiver**. For example, all three of the
>   following messages do the same thing:
>
> ```
> id myClone = [anObject copy];
> id myClone = [anObject performSelector:@selector(copy)];
> id myClone = [anObject performSelector:sel_getUid("copy")];
> ```
>
> However, the performSelector: method **allows you to send messages that
>   aren’t determined until runtime**. A variable selector can be passed as
>   the argument:
>
> ```
> SEL myMethod = findTheAppropriateSelectorForTheCurrentSituation();
> [anObject performSelector:myMethod];
> ```
>
> The aSelector argument should identify a method that takes no
>   arguments. For methods that return anything other than an object, use
>   NSInvocation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @stackBlue You're welcome. I marked bold the main parts from Apple doc. Upvote if you want :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

A `selector` object lets you call a method that you do not know at compile time. You need to know only the name of a method as a string in order to call it.

When the name of the method that you are calling is known at compile time, using selectors is counterproductive: the code becomes less readable for no apparent advantage. When you are writing a library that needs to call methods in other code that is compiled separately from the library, selectors provide a way to decouple the two pieces of code.

For example, if you are writing a timer class that can call you back when a time interval is over, your timer does not know the name of the function that it needs to call, so it cannot write something like this:

```
// We do not know if the function is called intervalHasExpired or something else
[target intervalHasExpired];
```

But if you give your timer a selector, the timer would be able to call you back.

```
[myTimer scheduleWithTarget:self andSelector:@selector(myCompletion)];
```

Answer (score 2):

PerformSelector basically allows you to decide what message to pass during runtime (late binding), as opposed to languages like plain C. If you know the name to a method in an objective C class, you can use

```
NSSelectorFromString()
```

To convert a string into a selector, and have your class call that selector using performSelector. In this way, you can choose different functions to call during runtime. You can even select which function to call using a config file.

Answer (score 1):

`performSelector` calls a method that has been declared and implemented in the class.  It is used when you need to attach an action in code to a event.