# Calling methods when UITableViewCell is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to call a method when a `UITableViewCell` is selected/tapped. I could do it easily with a static table view, but it requires a `UITableViewController` which is not good for me in this case, therefore I'm using a normal vc.

I have 10 specified methods like this:

```
- (void) methodOne {
 NSLog(@"Do something");
}   
- (void) methodTwo {
 NSLog(@"Do something");
}

....
```

And I would like to call the `methodOne` when the first cell was tapped, call the `methodTwo` when the second cell was tapped and so on..

As a first step I set the `numberOfRowsInSection` to return 10 cells, but have no idea how could I connect the selected cells with the methods. Is there any quick way to do it? It would be a dirty solution to create 10 custom cells and set the every method manually for the custom cells, and there is no free place for it.

Comment: You need to implement all of the normal table view data source and delegate methods whether you use a `UITableViewController` or add your own table view to a `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method for whenever any cell is tapped on the table view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger selectedRow = indexPath.row; //this is the number row that was selected
    switch (selectedRow)
    {
        case 0:
             [self methodOne];
             break;
        default:
             break;
    }
}
```

Use `selectedRow` to identify which row number was selected. If the first row was selected, `selectedRow` will be `0`.

Don't forget to set the table view's delegate to your view controller. The view controller also has to conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

As long as the table view has a data source and a delegate, it doesn't matter what kind of view controller it is on. All a `UITableViewController` really is is a `UIViewController` that already has a table view on it and is that table view's delegate and data source.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array of `NSString`s with method names in the order they should be called from their corresponding `UITableViewCell`s.

```
NSArray *selStringsArr = @[@"firstMethod", @"secondMethod", @"thirdMethod];
```

Then create a `selector` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` from the strings array and call it using `performSelector:`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *selString = selStringsArr[indexPath.row];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selString);

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(selector)]) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(selector)];
    }
}
```

Of course, there are some limitations to using `performSelector:` which you can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1493486/1921723).